# Coveo index does not update Item

Tags: indexing, coveo

I am facing an issue with Coveo search. In website's search results page, when I click a search result, it is throwing me a 404 error. In CES indexcontent, if I search same item and click on the Uri, it throws a 404 in CES as well. So I tried updated a field of the item, Coveo reindexed the item. In CES, I can see that item details updated. When I click uri in CES, it is still throwing a 404. Can you please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this happening with 1 item or all items? Anything in the logs?

Comment: Are you using Coveo for Sitecore version 3 or version 4?


What is the link that appears on your item and what are you expecting instead of the link that gives you a "404 error"

Comment: Thanks @OwenNiblock.. It was a content authoring issue and the issue is fixed now. One of the required fields for coveo index was not populated in sitecore. Later when I checked the logs, i was able to figure this out. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Thanks @flguillemette It was a content authoring issue and the issue is fixed now. One of the required fields for coveo index was not populated in sitecore. Later when I checked the logs, i was able to figure this out. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Karthik
Could you post an official answer with how you fixed it? That would help people in the future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One key field required for Coveo index was not filled with value in sitecore. Due to this, when coveo indexed, it was unable to form the item url. On analysis, we found this out and reached out to the content author to update the item field values.

We did reindex again and coveo was able to form the correct item url. Thanks everyone for helping.